# Unterschied: Verkleidung vs. Kostümierung

Tags: regional, difference

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen den beiden Wörtern?

Ich habe den Eindruck, dass man *Verkleidung* öfter als *Kostümierung* verwendet. Stimmt das bei euch?

Comment: Wer genau ist »bei euch«? Wer wäre denn »bei uns«?

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Ich verstehe nicht was Sie meinen.

Comment: Someone downvoted my question. For improvement purposes, would you be so kind to explain what's wrong with it? I thought the difference between these words is real.

Comment: Was ist deine Muttersprache? What is your native language? ([your profile](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/22441/hartmut) is rather empty). In case it is English: I asked: *Who exactly is "at you"? Who would be "at us"?* I was referring to your question "Stimmt das bei euch?" (*"Is this correct at you?"*) - btw: It wasn't me who downvoted your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Die beiden Worte haben nur eine gemeinsame Bedeutung:

> Anziehen von Kleidung um in eine andere Rolle zu schlüpfen (Clown, Cowboy, Teufel, etc.)

Dabei ist das Wort Kostümieren sehr spezifisch auf entsprechende Events bezogen. Das kann Fastnacht / Fasching / Karneval sein oder eben ein Theaterstück o.ä.
Wenn ich eine Kostümierung trage ist es eigentlich immer offensichtlich, dass das nicht meine normale Kleidung ist.
Ein Kostüm dient üblicherweise dazu, aufzufallen.

Das Wort `Verkleidung` ist universeller einsetzbar. So kann sich beispielsweise ein Geheimagent `verkleiden`, um nicht erkannt zu werden. Hier ist nicht unbedingt ersichtlich, dass er nicht seine übliche Kleidung trägt, und der Zweck ist gerade entgegengesetzt dem Kostüm: er möchte NICHT auffallen.

Zusätzlich hat die Verkleidung auch noch weitere Bedeutungen, die Kostümierung nicht hat:

Eine Verkleidung kann auch die Ummantelung eines Gegenstands sein, ich kann zum Beispiel einen hässlichen Kabelschacht mit Holz "verkleiden", um ihn zu verbergen / verschönern.

Der Duden listet hier als Synonyme die Worte `Bespannung, Verblendung, Vertäfelung` auf.

Insofern stimmt der Eindruck: Verkleidung wird häufiger eingesetzt wegen der spezielleren / engeren Bedeutung von Kostümierung.

Answer (score 2):

Das Wort "Verkleidung" wird im Alltag weit häufiger benutzt als "Kostümierung". Auch als Verb: ich kann mich nicht erinneren (in Deutschland, vielleicht ist es anders in Österreich und der Schweiz) die Frage zu hören "wirst du dich kostümieren?". "Wirst du dich verkleiden" wird viel häufiger gesagt.

@Tom Au: Meiner Meinung nach muss Verkleidung nicht zwangsläufig mit normaler Kleidung sein. "Ich werde mich als Kürbis verkleiden" hört sich für mich normal an, zumindest im normalen Sprachgebrauch.

Answer (score 0):

Die Kostümierung ist ein besonderen Sort der Verkleidung.

"Verkleidung meint dass man "normalen" Kleider trägt.

In Amerika, trägt man die Kostumer fur z.B. Halloween. Das ist, für ein Event.